# Lambda expression to generate a sublist based on existence of an entry

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a simple List which is ordered.

```
A = ["a","b","c","d","e"];
```

I need to generate a subset of the list based on the criteria. If an element `E` exists in the array, then return all the elements in the List after the element `E`, otherwise return `null`.

Normally, I'd do this something like:

```
int index = A.indexOf("e");
List<String> subList = A.subList(index, A.size());
```

Can this be done with an equivalent lambda expression?

Comment: What does the list being ordered have to do with anything? Then, as far as your code goes, don't you need to include a check that `index >= 0`? Also, you need to supply a variable name for the sublist. Finally, the second argument to `subList` is exclusive, so you should pass `A.size()` instead of `A.size() - 1` to avoid chopping off the last element.

Comment: I think the question has its merits. It gave me the opportunity to play with a stateful Predicate, which I hadn't done in the past.

Comment: The thing, you’d do normally, still is the best solution. Well, if the list is sorted, you may use `int index = Collections.binarySearch(A, "e");` instead. Then proceed with `List<String> subList = index<0? null: A.subList(index, A.size());`. Stream do neither, binary search nor `subList`, collecting into a new `List` is not the same as getting a `subList`.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements of the list are [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), then you could do it like this:

```
List<String> subList = list.stream()
    .filter(elem -> elem.compareTo("e") > 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This returns an empty list.

Slightly changing the filter condition:

```
List<String> subList = list.stream()
    .filter(elem -> elem.compareTo("e") >= 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Returns a list that only contains `"e"`.

**Note that you don't need the list to be ordered for this to work.** Besides, you don't even need the element to be present in the list, i.e. if the list was as follows:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "d", "e");
```

And you modify the filter condition to return elements after `"c"`:

```
List<String> subList = list.stream()
    .filter(elem -> elem.compareTo("c") > 0)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result would be `["d", "e"]`.

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to use Java 8 Streams and Lambads, you could use a stateful Predicate

```
public class IsAfterString implements Predicate<String> {

    private final String stringToWatchFor;
    private boolean foundString = false;

    public IsAfterString(String stringToWatchFor) {
      this.stringToWatchFor = stringToWatchFor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean test(String s) {

      if (foundString) {
        return true;
      }

      foundString = stringToWatchFor.equals(s);
      return false;
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
List<String> a = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
IsAfterString predicate = new IsAfterString("c");
List<String> list = a.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
list = predicate.hasFoundString() ? list : null;

System.out.println(list);
```

This will print the following statements:

- Element E is "c" => [d,e]
- Element E is "e" => []
- Element E is "g" => null

Note that this predicate will not work if you use `parallelStream`.

Comment: Stateful predicates are a bad idea, and are outlawed by the specification of Stream.  So not really a good idea to teach bad practices to someone who doesn't really know better.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Indeed, link to the spec https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate- And the page on Statelessness https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness